# Problem with encoding and terminals with Special Characters

Tags: c, encoding, codeblocks

I'm making a code and as im progressing the encoding changes to UTF-8, but that created a problem for me, im brazilian and i have some phrases in portuguese with special characters that are in ASCII table, but having to revise every printf and every phrase or word to see if have a special character is madness in a 700 line code, i have a short time so i tried changing the encoding to ***ISO-8859-1,UNICODE and WINDOWS-1252*** but the moment when i build or save the file it returns to UTF-8, i tried changing the **setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.utf8")** or anything but nothing happens, i tought that was the Code::Blocks terminal that was broken then i made a new test file to see with WINDOWS-1252 encoding worked, anyone has any ideia to help or i'd have to make character by character?

Im using the default terminal of codeblocks **cb_*console*_runner**

Isn't the encoding UTF-8 enconding and bytes that is incompatible with special characters? Because the default in UNICODE is 16bytes or am i wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    printf("%s", setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.utf8"));
}
```

returned: (NULL)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){
    printf("%s", setlocale(LC_ALL,""));
}
```

returned: Portuguese_Brazil.1252

as i looked in previewed questions in portuguese stackoverflow none has helped at all, some says is the encoding, others says is the terminal.

Comment: Unicode is Unicode and it defines some encodings: UTF-16 and UTF-8 are three of them (yeah, UTF-16 are two encodings), they are fully compatible. File may have a encoding, and it is totally different from locale setting. Can you provide a minimal example of your code (with strings), so we may see the problem? Or we have also a sister site in Portuguese: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Thiaguinhu123: "i tried changing the setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.utf8")" --> What was the return value from the `setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR.utf8")` function call?

Comment: I don't know the details of your environment, but often, the thing that matters is something in that environment, not something in your C code.  It's easy, for example, to write a C program that outputs special characters using well-formed, modern, UTF-8-encoded Unicode.  What can be significantly harder is to get your environment to properly display the characters as output by your C program.  Getting that to work may involve settings on the terminal emulator in which your program runs, or settings on the IDE under which your program runs.

Comment: UTF-8 is the defacto standard for many modern applications and systems. It is backward compatible with the ASCII standard character set and C code string handling routines, even though it may have 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes (octets) per character. No bytes are blank other than the null terminator at the end of a string. Unless your C code is looking for handling specific multi-byte character no changes will be required for data input or output.

Comment: Note that strict ASCII is a 7-bit code set and has zero accented characters in it.

Answer (score 1):

So, yesterday i talked to my professor and we both agreed that was the encoding, but he had an idea, i got my code and opened in Dev-C++ and as we noticed the file was "corrupted" with the special letters as i mentioned i think it was from when the file was been saved in UTF8 that changed.